# Cannot find H2 Db Syntax for USING INDEX ENABLE equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, h2

Running Spring Boot App with Liquibase changeset

My main code uses Oracle to run the sql query but my integration test cases are using H2 database to run the same query.

below is my **db/changelog/db.changelog-quartz.sql** file.

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset quartz:quartz-init

ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS ADD PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, LOCK_NAME) USING INDEX  ENABLE;
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS MODIFY ("LOCK_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS MODIFY ("SCHED_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

above query works when I **run** **manually** in Oracle but these query does not work when I run them via **Integration Test cases** because may be my test cases are using h2 database.

Can someone please share the syntax of **"using index enable" in H2**

when I run **Integration test cases** then I am getting below error

```
 Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS ADD PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, LOCK_NAME) USING[*] INDEX  ENABLE"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS ADD PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, LOCK_NAME) USING INDEX  ENABLE [42000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
```

Extra information:

version of jdbc : **com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8: 19.11.0.0**

Below is my integration test sample:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = TestApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-scheduler-test.yml")
public class TelSecSchedulerComponentTestIT {

    @Autowired
    private BatchJobScheduler batchJobScheduler;

    @Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
  
    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, InvalidBatchJobStatusException, SchedulerException, InterruptedException {
        
    }
```

and below is my **application-scheduler-test.yml** file

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
  quartz:
    job-store-type: memory
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          jobStore:
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
            dataSource: myTestDB
          dataSource:
            myTestDB:
              driver: org.h2.Driver
              URL: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
              user: sa
              password:
              provider: hikaricp
              validationQuery: select 1
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
      ddl-auto: none
    generate-ddl: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    contexts: scheduler-test
    change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

I am not sure what **syntax error** I have in the query.

can some one please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

All these commands are Oracle-specific.

For H2 (or any other standard-compliant DBMS) you need to execute the following commands:

```sql
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS ALTER COLUMN "LOCK_NAME" SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS ALTER COLUMN "SCHED_NAME" SET NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS ADD PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, LOCK_NAME);
```

In Oracle compatibility mode of H2 (and in real Oracle too) you can alternatively use

```sql
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS MODIFY ("LOCK_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS MODIFY ("SCHED_NAME" NOT NULL ENABLE);
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_LOCKS ADD PRIMARY KEY (SCHED_NAME, LOCK_NAME);
```

To enable this mode you can add `;MODE=Oracle` to JDBC URL.

In any case the primary key constraint in H2 may only be created when `NOT NULL` constraints were already created.

There is no equivalent for `USING INDEX ENABLE` in H2, H2 always uses indexes for primary key, unique, and referential constraints.

Comment: Evgenij,  Can you please help on syntax for below query ?  since below query has syntax issue in Oracle compatibility mode of H2.                               
ALTER TABLE QRTZ_TRIGGERS ADD CONSTRAINT "QRTZ_TRIGGERS_SCHED_NAME_FKEY" FOREIGN KEY ("SCHED_NAME", "JOB_NAME", "JOB_GROUP")
    REFERENCES QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS ("SCHED_NAME", "JOB_NAME", "JOB_GROUP") ENABLE;

Comment: You need to remove `ENABLE`, there is no such clause in the SQL Standard and H2.